# How to find a String not surrounded by pipes in a pipe delimited file?

Tags: java, regex, regex-negation, regex-lookarounds

I am trying to find a regex that will match any pair of double quotes, that does not have exactly one pipe in front of it, and one pipe after it.

Here is the example line:

```
1||1|0|0|1|0|""|0|0|||""|""Billy""|"Johnson"|
```

In this line I would want to match the pairs of double quotes in front of and behind the word `Billy`.

The regex I tried is:

```
[^|]""[^|]
```

Which seems straightforward enough, but fails to match how I would think.

Is there a regex that will match those?

(Specifically I will be trying to replace those quotes in Java using `String.replaceAll()`, but a general regex solution would be fine at getting me started in the right direction.)

Comment: Any particular language/regex engine in mind?

Comment: Hopefully clarified, will be using Java ultimately

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to escape the | symbol, because it has special meaning in RegEx.

Try `[^\|]""[^\|]` instead.  You can verify this using online tools, like the one at http://www.roblocher.com/technotes/regexp.html

However, building off of anubhava's suggestion, you're looking for matches on the Quotes only, not the text in-between.  Try this instead:

`(?<!\|)""|""(?!\|)`

It will match a string where there is not a | before the "", OR where there is not a | after the ""

Comment: You can use the RegEx Demo that anubhava linked to for confirming if the regex should work in your case.

Comment: Credit goes to anubhava for the negative lookbehind and negative lookahead clauses, as I had forgotten about those.

Answer (score 2):

You can use this regex:

```
(?<!\|)"[^|"]+"(?!\|)
```

#### [RegEx Demo](http://regex101.com/r/fQ5uS8/1)

Comment: This does a great job of matching the "Billy" which I may be able to use, but I am actually trying to match the "" in front of it and the "" after it, but not and of the other "" that are between pipes